# inserting special symbol dot (.) into sqlite?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, special-characters

I insert the following text in the database:

```
.Pour lemon juice immediately on fruits. 
.In a little water add sugar and half melt it on heat. 
.Mix melted sugar to the fruits. Refrigerate it and serve the fruit salad chilled. 
.Note: Salt and chaat masala can also be used
```

Inserting this data does not produce an error but when I display the above data 
I am getting this:

```
‚Ä¢ Pour lemon juice immediately on fruits. 
‚Ä¢ In a little water add sugar and half melt it on heat. 
‚Ä¢ Mix melted sugar to the fruits. Refrigerate it and serve the fruit salad chilled. 
‚Ä¢ Note: Salt and chaat masala can also be used
```

The period is replaced by `‚Ä¢`.

Please guide me, how can I display inserted period symbol instead of above output.

Comment: You just put dots in your strings, it's really not a problem usually. What have you tried?

Comment: Its better if you can post code for SQLite Insert Statement so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make sure that the character you are inserting is actually what you think it is, such as U+2e, the ASCII period.

There are a great many "full stop" characters as you can see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=.&preview=entity), and it only takes the use of one of the "non-standard" variants to choke up an application that doesn't know how to render it.

It's also possible that the three character sequence you're seeing (`‚Ä¢`) is actually just the UTF-8 encoding of the character you're inserting.

This is probably the more likely case since those leading "periods" in your text probably make more sense as bullet point margers, such as with [U+2022](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) which would give you the UTF-8 code `0xe2 0x80 0xa2` (0xa2 is the cent symbol - although the other bytes don't match, that's the sort of thing you're looking for).

Probably your best chance of finding out is to log the data that you're sending to the SQL INSERT statement into a file somewhere, then do a hex dump of that file to see what the errant character is.

If it's anything other than the ASCII-style period at U+2e, that may be what's causing the trouble.

Even though SQLite may be able to *store* it, that doesn't guarantee that whatever you're using to *display* it is up to the task.